# How do I make a TextInput show the start of the entered text instead of the end in Android?

Tags: android, react-native, textinput

I have a `TextInput` in my react-native application. When I set the value prop and the value is longer than the length of the `TextInput`, it shows the text starting from the end and not the beginning. In iOS it works okay, it seems to be an Android issue. Is there a way to align the text to show from the start of the `TextInput` or whichever is the preferred?

**This is what I see:**

[image]

**This is what I want:**

[image]

Here's my code

```
<TextInput
defaultValue={address}
ref="searchInput"
autoCorrect={false}
style={searchStyles.searchInputField}
placeholderTextColor={'#ddd'}
placeholder="Location"
onChangeText={query => this.search(query)}
/>
```

Comment: for android `android:ellipsize="end" `

Answer (score 12):

I ran into the same issue my solution for this was adding the [selection](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#selection) prop to the start by default. This works so when the input is focused it goes to the start. I then added the [autoFocus](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#autofocus) prop and set it to true to make it go to the start when the component is loaded.

```
<TextInput value={address} autoFocus={true} selection={{start:0, end:0}} />
```

There may be a better way to do this but this is what i have come up with hope it helps others.

Comment: but this way the user can't move the cursor anymore

Comment: @wong2 i imagine your component must be being re rendered on a change or something similar which could cause that problem.

Comment: Gave an answer similar to yours just now. But, you should not add the 'end' attribute, that way it'll start there but won't limit the user for changes or cursor move

Comment: @YossiSaadi Nice, its been a while since i used it but i think i slightly remember having trouble with excluding 'end' this may have been changed with any updates over the last year or could've been just for my particular use case.

Comment: @AidanDoherty It does cause a little trouble, you are now allowing the user to make a selection, but the positive is he can scroll. Still no perfect solution :)

Comment: I can't move cursor anymore , this solution is for fix position.

Comment: @vishalrathod Has been a while since i done this but can you try and prevent any re renders on the component you are trying to do it with and see if that stops the cursor position reseting? There also may be a better way of doing this now since i last looked into it... i hope, best of luck.

Answer (score 9):

Add `selection={{start:0}}` without the `end` attribute

Answer (score 6):

try this its working for me

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 
 this.state = {
   selection: Platform.OS === 'android' ? { start: 0 } : null
 }
}

onFocus =()=>{
  if(Platform.OS==='android'){
    this.setState({ selection:null });
  }
}

onBlur =()=>{
  if(Platform.OS==='android'){
    this.setState({ selection:{ start: 0, end: 0 } });
  }
}

<TextInput
  onFocus={()=>this.onFocus()}
  onBlur={()=>this.onBlur()}
  selection={this.state.selection}
/>
```

Comment: it's working but minor issue , first time cursor is not moving I need to do second move for cursor position.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.inputRef &&
        this.inputRef.setNativeProps({ selection: { start: 0, end: 0 } })
```

Put the code in onEndEditing and wherever you want to update the text.

Or update the text and selection at the same time:

```
this.inputRef &&
        this.inputRef.setNativeProps({ text: value, selection: { start: 0, end: 0 } })
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and the following worked for me,

> default - selection={start:0}
>
> onFocus - selection={null}
>
> onBlur - selection={start:0}

If you use functional component it goes like this.

```
const TextInputFromFirst = () => {

const [selection, setSelection] = useState({start: 0});
const handleFocus = () => {
    setSelection(null);
};
const handleBlur = () => {
    setSelection({start: 0});
};

return (
<TextInput
        placeholder="Enter Some Long Text"
        onBlur={handleBlur}
        onFocus={handleFocus}
        selection={selection}
/>
)
```

Answer (score -3):

`ellipsizeMode="head"` or You can try `ellipsizeMode="tail"`

Comment: I don't think this is the thing he is looking for this solution will change the truncation of the text not the starting position of the TextInput. "Beginning" should always be shown when the input is loaded and then you can swipe left to view the rest of the value.

Comment: `ellipsizeMode` prop only support by `Text` component