# React Native TextInput - Move to the beginning of the input after losing focus

Tags: react-native, mobile

I'm having trouble configuring a TextInput to always show the input value from the beginning when the component loses focus.

I have this:

[image: current]

I want this:

[image: objective]

This is my component:

```
export function TextInputField(props: TextInputFieldProps): React.JSX.Element {
    return (
        <View style={{...ModalStyles.inputContainer, width: props.width}}>
            <Text style={ModalStyles.inputLabel}>{props.text}</Text>
            <View style={getTextInputStyle(props)}>
                <TextInput style={ModalStyles.textInputField}/>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

I'm testing in Android.

I've tried to set the `selection` as suggested here: [How do I make a TextInput show the start of the entered text instead of the end in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48803533/how-do-i-make-a-textinput-show-the-start-of-the-entered-text-instead-of-the-end) , but without success.